# Как отследить этапы отправки запроса к сервису?

Tags: reactjs, https

При нажатии на кнопку "приложить пропуск" отправляется запрос к сервису пропусков.

При отправке запроса большое  количество времени (около 10s) занимает Connection Start, а только после этого выполняется сам запрос.
Все это время  пользователь ждет.

Мне нужно отследить, когда Connection Start закончится, чтобы оповестить пользователя об этом. (чтобы он приложил пропуск и авторизовался)

Можно ли как-то это сделать?

Я пробовала использовать XMLHttpRequest, но этот способ не работает, как  мне нужно.